# RTSP stream in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ffmpeg, rtsp, live555

I'm new to `Objective-C`.
How to read an `RTSP` stream in an `iOS` app?

Apparently libraries `live555` and `ffmpeg` are able, but I find no such simple and functional.

Are there other solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

All solutions use ffmpeg.

But some are easier than others, here's a tutorial to get you started.

http://sol3.typepad.com/exotic_particles/

personally I find live 555 offers the most options but also is quite hard to get started with.
most of the difficulty is usually in building ffmpeg libs.

Comment: The project RTSPPlay from your link is what I want. But I can't to start it into the iPhone simulator.
There is an example with FFmpeg or Live555 works?

Comment: Yes all these samples only work on devices, seriously the performance between the simulator and the device for these types of apps is so different its a waste of time to do. I am sure live555 has samples on there site but they are a lot harder to work with then anything we have here.BTW we now have examples of using our non -sdl ffmpeg/avfoundation framework.